# How to calculate the maximum Elongation of Mercury seeing from the Earth?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, orbital-motion, astronomy, geometry, solar-system

I want to calculate the maximum [Elongation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elongation_(astronomy)) of mercury seeing from the Earth but not by this assumption that  its orbit is circle but it is an ellipse with semimajor axis a = 0.387 AU and e = 0.2 and Earth's orbit is a circle with radius 1 AU. How can I find it?

Comment: Mercury appears biggest when viewed from the earth when it is closest to the earth. I'm guessing that you are looking for the maximum distance between the earth and mercury (with the understanding that you cannot see mercury when it is behind the sun).

Comment: @R.W.Bird No, the [elongation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elongation_(astronomy)) is the angular separation between Mercury and Sun as seen from the Earth.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

As you already know the greatest elongation of Mercury is given by
$$\tan\phi=\frac{r}{r_\text{Earth}}. \tag{1}$$

Given Mercury's semi-major axis $a$ and eccentricity $e$,
its distance from the sun varies between
$r_\text{min}=a(1-e)$ and $r_\text{max}=a(1+e)$.

Then you can just use (1) with Mercury's maximal radius $r_\text{max}$
to calculate its maximal greatest elongation $\phi_\text{max}$.